# Modules and calling subroutines in Perl

Tags: perl, module

I'm having a problem getting a specific subroutine to work, i have my module "module1.pm" and i have my testscript "testmodule.pl". Here is the code for testmodule.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Basename qw(dirname);
use Cwd qw(abs_path);
use lib dirname(dirname abs_path $0) . '/perl/lib';
use warnings;
use strict;
use Report::module1 qw(userloggins PasswordAge DiskUsage);

#Gets the users from module1::userloggins() and sorts them
my $PasswordAge;
my %userhash = Report::module1::userloggins ();
print "Here are the users that have logged in and how many times they've logged in.\n";
foreach my $user (sort { $userhash{$b} <=> $userhash{$a}  ||  $a cmp $b } keys(%userhash)) {

print("$user: $userhash{$user}\n");
}
print "----------------------------------------------\n";

#PasswordAge

print "How many days would you like to check users for old passwords?\n";
my $input = <>;
my @UserPassChange = PasswordAge (int($input), keys(%userhash) );
for my $i (0...$#UserPassChange) {
print ("User $UserPassChange[$i] has not changed their password in $input days.\n");
} 
print "----------------------------------------------\n";

#DiskUsage
print "Input size for checking users home folder: ";
my $input2 = <>;
my %DiskUsageReturned = Report::module1::DiskUsage (int($input2),     keys(%userhash) );
#print %DiskUsageReturned;
foreach my $user (%DiskUsageReturned){
print("$user: $DiskUsageReturned{$user}\n");
}
```

And here is the code for module1.pm:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


use warnings;
use strict;
package Report::module1;
use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK=qw(userloggins PasswordAge DiskUsage);

sub DiskUsage {

my $userInput = shift @_;
my @users = @_;
my %DiskUsageHash;

foreach my $user (@users){
print "$user";
my $UserDiskUsage = int(`du -bs /home/$user | cut -f1`);
my $Mebi = int ($UserDiskUsage / 1048576);
if ($Mebi >= $userInput){
    #print @UserDiskUsage;
$DiskUsageHash{$user} = $Mebi;
}
}


return %DiskUsageHash;

}

1;
```

I cannot seem to figure what i'm doing wrong when using subroutines within my module. It fetches the users with a home folder that is bigger than whatever i input, but i also get a lot of error messages. This is the output i get when i run "testmodule.pl".

```
Input size for checking users home folder: 5
maholilaelita15vicnigigaaddahepemaskmaho: 14
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at testmodule.pl line 36, <> line 2.
14: 
lila: 9
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at testmodule.pl line 36, <> line 2.
9: 
giga: 7
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at testmodule.pl line 36, <> line 2.
7: 
elit: 123
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at testmodule.pl line 36, <> line 2.
123: 
adda: 65
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at testmodule.pl  line 36, <> line 2.
65: 
hepe: 188
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at testmodule.pl  line 36, <> line 2.
188: 
mask: 94
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at testmodule.pl   line 36, <> line 2.
94:
```

Comment: Well, that first code snippet doesn't even compile, because `%userhash` isn't defined. Both are less than 36 lines long, so that can't be the right error message either.

Comment: @Sobrique There, i fixed it. Hadn't copied the whole code.

Comment: @nillenilsson Is your indentation really that bad, or is it just an artifact of copying and pasting?

Comment: also read about [mcve] :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
foreach my $user (%DiskUsageReturned) {
    print("$user: $DiskUsageReturned{$user}\n");
}
```

You need a `keys` in there. Otherwise you're getting both 'user' and 'disk usage' treated *as if* they were a user. Because when you evaluate a hash in a list context - like you are - every element of the hash is returned (in a random order, but with keys and values paired). So half the elements will be numeric, and not correspond to a key in the hash, because they're a value instead.

Illustration:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my %stuff = (
    "me"  => 5,
    "you" => 6,
);
#does the same error, because it tries to look up 
#the value associated with '5' and '6' in the hash. 
foreach my $thing (%stuff) {
    print "$thing\n";
    print "$thing => $stuff{$thing}\n";
}
#doesn't, because "keys %stuff" returns ( "you", "me" )
foreach my $thing ( keys %stuff ) {
    print "$thing => $stuff{$thing}\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm trying to understand so here i tested it like this in my code but i still get the same error messages:

    `foreach my $user (%DiskUsageReturned){
    print("$user: $DiskUsageReturned{keys}\n");
}`

Comment: You need to run `keys` on the hash, to return the user list. `foreach my $user ( keys %DiskUsageReturned ) { `

Comment: Thanks that dit it! Do you happen to know why my thread has -2 points and what i can do in the future to avoid it ?

Comment: @nillenilsson I would assume your question is getting downvoted because: a) you're asking people to debug your code for you, b) your indentation and formatting is poor, and c) it's not a [mcve] (note the "minimal" part).